# ALTER TABLE to append ENUM values from subquery

Tags: mysql, enums, race-condition, alter-table

I've looked around for a while, but I am having trouble finding the answer to this. I want to run a single `ALTER TABLE` to append values to an `ENUM` field, without hitting any race conditions. The best way I can think of is something similar to this:

```
ALTER TABLE 'my_table' MODIFY COLUMN 'my_enum' *results_from_subquery_here*
```

where the subquery is the following:

```
(SELECT column_type,  concat(TRIM(TRAILING ')' FROM column_type),",'new_enum_value')")
FROM information_schema.columns
as T
WHERE table_name = 'my_table'
and column_name ='my_enum')
```

Which clearly can't just be appended to the first like that.

I've seen certain approaches that use `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE`, or trivially via dbi (in perl), but I want to know if it is possible to do without them. Ie, I want to know if it can be done in a single statement, and avoid race conditions.

Also, I know that `ENUM`s are "evil", in case you were about to mention that.

Answer (score 1):

No, this operation cannot be performed in a single statement.

The `ALTER TABLE` statement doesn't have any support for running a `SELECT` subquery. Which is why you've found what you found: a separate `SELECT` statement being run, and then a second `ALTER TABLE` statement being run.

---

**FOLLOWUP**

To get this type of operation to be "atomic", you'd need to obtain an exclusive lock on the table. The `ALTER TABLE` does get an exclusive lock, but I think you're asking about two sessions...

```
session   operation
-------   -----------------------
one       get enum defn ('a','b') and add 'c'
two       get enum defn ('a','b') and add 'fee'
two       set enum defn ('a','b','fee')
one       set enum defn ('a','b','c')
```

To prevent one from "overwriting" the other, you'd need to establish some sort of locking mechanism to prevent two sessions from performing this operation concurrently.

(I don't think `ENUM`s are evil; yes, there are some limitations, and we need to take care in using the `ENUM` datatype.)

Comment: Hmm.. that's what I feared. Thanks.

Comment: If I've understood it correctly, even with a `PREPARE-EXECUTE` it would not prevent a race condition either, right? Because while I am preparing, the `ENUM` might change, and then on `EXECUTE` it would just overwrite it, right?